# How do I set up Ubuntu to boot by default in dual boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I dual booted my laptop by installing Ubuntu 14.04 along with Windows 8.1. Now when I power on my laptop by default it boots with Windows. How can I set Ubuntu to boot by default?

Comment: do you see any boot option screen?

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the file `/etc/default/grub`.

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

The default entry is determined by the `GRUB_DEFAULT=` setting in this file. The first `menuentry` has a value of `0`. If Ubuntu is the second entry in the boot screen then set `GRUB_DEFAULT=1`.

Afterwards you need to run this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

For further information see this [article on help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring_GRUB_2)

Comment: it is showing that you don't have permission to edit this file.

Comment: does sudo vim /etc/default/grub or sudo nano /etc/default/grub work?

Comment: No its not working. :(

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: When i start my laptop and go to boot menu then i choose Ubuntu to boot..  Then 4 options come.... ...  This method changes  option in these four menus.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that fast start mode in Windows is disabled. It happened with me. 
Disable it and shutdown and start your machine again.

google about disabling this mode for more info